# Unable to do cross filtering

Tags: dc.js

So There is one line chart that is working fine so now I am trying to add 2 more graphs so that I can see the interaction between them by cross-filtering.

When I select range interval from bar chart then I get this **error:**

```
VM357 dc.js:3697 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined
    at prepareXAxis (VM345 dc.js:3697)
    at drawChart (VM345 dc.js:4426)
    at Object._chart._doRedraw (VM345 dc.js:4415)
    at Object._chart.redraw (VM345 dc.js:2138)
    at Object.dc.redrawAll (VM345 dc.js:279)
    at Object._chart.redrawGroup (VM345 dc.js:2190)
    at Object._chart.applyBrushSelection (VM345 dc.js:4296)
    at VM345 dc.js:4289
    at VM345 dc.js:1241
```

**Working demo + Code:**

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/ad4ab375e1a14f3e151c5b13a60ecef5

that line chart has 2 types:

1) `composite chart` which is defined under `function comp_chart` (**Line no: 396-434**)

2) `Single Line chart` which is defined next to the above.

So all the graphs are getting rendered in **line 558**.
Those 2 kind of line chart is rendered in `function setup()` **line no: 529** also.

That `bar chart` is defined under `composite2`

I don't know how to tackle this error.

**Edit:**
See it works for me right now.

[image]

Comment: I haven’t looked at your block (on mobile) but the error means you didn’t supply `.x()` scale.

Comment: But I have defined `.x()` for every graph

Comment: I guess you kept working on it, because I get a different error (`top_states` is undefined). Probably a good idea to fork when you continue to work on a notebook linked in a question

Comment: No actually this is the error you will get at the end of the day only.  Check again it works. That error you got it now, is a bug. Which I got it yesterday but could not solve it because when a new day comes a new row gets added up so this error went away. I need to solve this bug also. So after few min when there is addiion of data and then you will check it will work.

Comment: My data1 last row was not able to get added up with the last row of data2. So my `statewise` tag was missing in the last row of final data. That's why this error came.

Comment: I don't understand - should I try again in a few hours? I still see the error and one blank chart.

Comment: But I am able to see it. check my edit. There is this bug when concatenating two json data. It missed the last row so last row doesn't have the combined things. That's why that error appeared. I was trying to resolve this bug in my code but then new day came and data got added up. So I was left with no bug.  I will use two for loops and match by dates and then combine it. this will solve the problem although not an optimized solution.

Comment: there are two api. So I guess if one of them gets updates and other doesn't . Then there will be size difference. Since I am concatenating by index not by comparing dates so the last row will be buggy unless the other api updates itself and their size becomes the same. Will resolve it today itself. @Gordon: I don't know why you are not able to see it. Right now it's working fine. I have not made any changes. This bug should not occur at this time. I will solve this bug in the morning. So that it won't give the error in `top_states`

Comment: Weird. I'm just getting one blank chart: https://imgur.com/LwCU82w I checked I am able to read the data sources okay. I'll take another look tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not a complete answer, because I don't have time to debug your project for you. I have diagnosed the specific problem and I have a suggestion only.

The specific problem you are encountering is that you have initialized two different charts into the same div, but only one of them is active at a time:

```
var composite = dc.compositeChart("#line-chart");
var composite2 = dc.barChart("#line-chart2");

var linechart = dc.lineChart("#line-chart")
```

When you start out, you have the composite chart initialized in `#line-chart`, but the other line chart is not initialized. Unfortunately, dc.js will still try to draw it! So that is why it is crashing.

My suggestion is to only use the composite chart, and re-initialize it with only one child chart when you display an individual state.

Otherwise you would have to go through the tedium of adding and removing charts from the chart registry, which is error-prone.

Notice that if you first switch to an individual state and then filter on the bar chart, you don't get the same error, but you run into problems with your legend toggling code instead, since it is still trying to read/update the composite chart even though it no longer exists.

I think it's going to be a headache to condition all of your code on which chart is active in the div, and it should be easier to only have one chart per div, especially since the line chart functionality is a strict subset of the composite.

Comment: BTW, the block worked fine for me today. A likely reason for a block working at some times of day but not others is time zone issues. I think you are about 10.5 hours ahead of me over there.

Comment: Yeah it's because of `new Date()` which I used for ending the loop.

Comment: So I should have two separate div for combined states and single states. I should hide/unhide the div instead based on selection. Am I correct?

Comment: Right now solving this time issue by removing `new Date()` <-- which gives me current date.

Comment: That might also work. I recommend only using the composite chart.

Comment: `only use the composite chart, and re-initialize it with only one child chart when you display an individual state.` . If possible can you share a example where child of the composite charts has been used. May be similar to this problem. Just a syntax part. How to render only child element of composite chart that will help.

Comment: No I meant initialize the composite chart with only one array element. Use the code you have but display one state instead of N. Sorry I don’t have any examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214668/discussion-between-pygirl-and-gordon).

Comment: Sorry I don’t do chat and I can’t help you further. It’s just a suggestion; I’m sure there are other ways to fix it. It’s software engineering at this point and not a question about dc.js

Comment: Not a problem :). Thanks for the hint and suggestion though. If this involves more of software engineering and not dc js, then I might be able to solve it.

Comment: I created a basic line chart (state) and checking for crossfiltering but it doesn;t seem to work. It's not changing anything at all. https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/aa3cd0608f3796bbe0bf4228b9388d99

Comment: Please ask another question - it isn't good to ask multiple questions in one SO question. I hope it's obvious that if the X dimension is the same (date) for both charts, the result isn't going to be very interesting.